# Can line breaks be used to separate properties?

Tags: typescript

[Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) says

> You can use `,` or `;` to separate the properties, and the last separator
> is optional either way.

Can line breaks be used to separate properties of an object like this? If so, is it written somewhere?

```
interface Foo {
  a: string
  b: string
}
```

Comment: Why not try it and find out: https://tsplay.dev/w2g1YN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not well-documented, but according to [a comment on microsoft/TypeScript#11856](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11856#issuecomment-256401912), TypeScript's rules for [automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion) are the same as JavaScript's rules.  That means if your code has a newline followed by an unexpected token, a semicolon will automatically be inserted.  Therefore

```
interface Foo {
  a: string
  b: string
}
```

is interpreted as

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: string
}
```

because `interface Foo { a: string b: string }` would be a syntax error at `b`.